# Speaker for Pi Zero W

Tags: audio, power, pi-zero-w, speakers

I'm looking for speaker without battery. I mean I need a speaker whose power can be supplied by raspberry pi zero w.

I think I can use USB 2.0 simple speaker. I can cut its usb cable and connect its 5V cable to Raspberry's 5V pin and its ground to ground. Is it possible? 
[image]

[image]

Moreover, jack input is not available for pi zero w as you know. So, I will use HDMI to VGA's audio output as seen the below picture. I don't want to use bluetooth option.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Look at ReSpeaker modules
https://respeaker.io

You can just plug the GPIO and the speaker through the JST-2.0 interface.
You can also connect MICS depending on hardware revision

Comment: :)) engineering is to do best with what you've got, not to have best doodads.. Evidently it is really expensive for a simple student

Comment: If you want to power a simple speaker to the RPI you can do it without problem if the speaker got powered on 3.3V or 5V.
A simple woofer is enough if you want to build also the cable ;)

Comment: Another option is to use the GPIO Pin as Audio Out on RPI, connecting the buzzer directly to GPIO, no HDMI to 3.5mm Jack needed

Comment: can I supply power with 3.3V  and 5V pins? Is there any speaker to use like that? I mean jack is from hdmi-vga converter, power  from pins??

Comment: Yes. Take a pair of speaker powered by 3.3V batteries.Remove the batteries and build the wire to connect the positive pole to 3.3 Out PIN on GPIO and the negative one to the Ground PIN. The speaker will power on correctly

Comment: of course by the way what about amplifiers? Seemingly there is no product for 5v and 3.3v. Must I use amplifiers?

Comment: The amplifier is your PC's Audio Card (HDMI pass the Video and Audio signals). So be sure you are using Passive Speaker. If you use PC Speaker you are ready to go with no problem.

Comment: **As last question**, if I cut usb 2.0 and connect it to 5v ad ground pin, it works? --> https://urun.n11.com/hoparlor-speaker/cyber-11-usb-speaker-hoparlor-an-2420-P130587078

Comment: No..This kind of speaker got like an internal audio card. So when you plug in the USB, your PC will install the driver needed to drive them. 
If you cut the USB2.0 cable and throw out the Positive/Negative PIN you just power the Speaker with the GPIO, but the sound connection must be through the original USB(without the power PINs connected), or you have to reimplement the same logic to communicate(called driver)

Comment: but its explanation says that usb cable to provide just power not for any data transmit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81579/discussion-between-madpapo-and-snr).